# Core Data: Predicate for first element in orderd relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, predicate, nsorderedset

I have this to-many relationship which contains at least one element:

```
Appointment <<------>> Invitee
```

`appointment.invitees` is an **ordered relationship** resulting in an `NSOrderedSet`.

In a table view controlled by a fetched results controller, I have the appointments listed, along with the first element of the invitees set.

Now I want to *search* this list by invitees' names, using an `NSPredicate`. But how can refer to the *first element* of the ordered list in the predicate?

I tried:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
       @"invitees[FIRST].lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchTerm];
```

but I get the `unimplemented SQL generation for predicate` error. This would make sense, as the result is a collection, but not strictly an array. Still, I think that the sqlite store must be modeling the order, so it should be retrievable.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, this a question that not even the most expert Core Data savants can answer.

The workaround is to model the first element as a separate to-one relationship and the rest as an optional to-many relationship based on the same related entity.

```
Appointment <<------>  mainInvitee        (Invitee)
            <<------>> additionalInvitees (Invitee)
```

Comment: Can you show your code please I have the same problem

Comment: @MertKöksal It's not a code problem, it is about data structure.

Comment: So you may help me with my question maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437589/default-core-data-value-assignment-swiftui

Comment: The question is deleted it seems.