# Have a couple of NSManagedObjects share a To-Many relationship in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

Let's say that I have a group of people. Each person can have a companion (most of the time will have a companion). This companionship is in charge of friendshipping other people.  A person can be friendshipped by only one companionship.

e.g. We have `John, Tom, Mary, Paul, Peter, Frank and Wil`

Peter and Tom friendship Paul and John, and so on:

```
Peter - Tom         Paul - Mary         Wil - John            Frank -
 |_Paul              |_Wil         
 |_John              |_Peter
                     |_Tom
```

`Mary` and `Frank` are not friendshipped by anyone. `Frank` does not have a companion.

I have set the following relationships:

```
Person
Relationship       Destination    Inverse            Type       Delete Rule
companion          Person         companion          To One     Nullify
friendshippedBy    Person         friendships        To Many    Nullify       Count 2 Maximum
friendships        Person         friendshippedBy    To Many    Nullify
```

I can find who's Peter's companion, who Peter friendships, who friendships Peter, who has not a companion, who is not friendshipping anyone and who is not being friendshipped. This is all good, it's everything that I need, except that I need to take care of some of the data integrity myself: I have to make sure that as long as Peter is Tom's companion, Peter and Tom friendship the same people (the `friendships` relationship **should** be the same for both).
I have to set these relationships with something like:

```
peter.friendships = [NSSet setWithArray:@[paul, john]];
tom.friendships = peter.friendships; // need to preserve it as long as they're companions
```

I want to avoid having to write the last line every time the `friendships` relationship changes for one of the people in a companionship.
I'm thinking I can write a convenience method on a category (I still have to make sure that I call that method instead of `.friendships =` directly or I have to override `setFriendships`), but what I'd really like is to have Core Data take care of this relationship by itself.

Is there a way to have Core Data preserve this relationship automatically?

Comment: What about introducing an intermediate entity that has a to-many relationship "companions" (max=2) and another to-many relationship "friendships"?

Comment: @MartinR I've been thinking about doing that, but I can't quite figure how to set up the `friendships` entity and still be able to relatively easy answer the questions I need an answer for (who is not being friendshipped, etc)... it might be easy, but I guess I'm stuck on the way I've done it so far.. any tips?

Comment: If the intermediate entity is called "Connection" then you would have two relationships from "Person" to "Connection", one is the inverse relationship to "companions" and one is the inverse relationship to "friendships". Lets call them "companionedBy" and "friendshippedBy" (there might be better names). People which are not friendshipped by anybody are those which have no related "Connection" object, i.e. those with "friendshippedBy = nil".

Comment: To get the companion of Peter, you would have to get "peter.companionedBy.companions", which is the set (Peter, Tom), and find the "other object". That could be done with an utility method or transient property.

Comment: @MartinR Brilliant! Works just like I need it to. It took me a while to figure it out, in my head I still wanted Person to drive the relationship, but instead Connection drives it which is just fine. Would you mind posting your comments as an answer so I can mark my question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of duplicating the "friendship" for all "companions", you could introduce an
intermediate Entity "Connection" that stores both the companions and the common friends:

[image]

(and set the maximum value for the "companions" relationship to 2).

Then

- `person.companionConnection.friendships` are the friends of a given `person`,
- `person.companionConnection.companions` is a set containing the given `person` and his
  companion,
- persons that are not friendshipped by anyone are those with `person.friendshipConnection = nil`.

Comment: I know the question has ben answered, but if I want to use the Connection entity for a sortDescriptor (I'm using a FetchedResultsController)... how would you do it sorting by any of the to-many relationships? I want to avoid adding an unneccesary attribute on Connection, and judging by your comments on other threads you might have a good idea on how to do it

Comment: @Eric: Can you elaborate a bit? What do you want to display and how should it be sorted?

Comment: I want to display the names of the Persons in a relationship, sorting by the name of first person in the companions set would work.

Comment: @Eric: That might be difficult. First of all, "first companion" would only make sense if companions is an *ordered* relationship. But even then, referring to the first element of an ordered relationship in a fetch request seems impossible, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394513/core-data-predicate-for-first-element-in-orderd-relationship for a similar issue. The only workaround that I can think of is that instead of a to-many relationship "companions" you define two to-one relationships "firstCompanion", "secondCompanion". Then you can sort by "companionConnection.firstCompanion".

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a 'auto-duplicate' feature. Use the option of overriding `setFriendships`. You could also use KVO to trigger the update. Another possibility is to not duplicate the relationships, instead, add a method which creates the union of the two people's relationships and returns that (depending on what you want to use the relationship contents for).