# LAST object from a to-many relationship in a NSPredicate - Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Is it possible to use `NSPredicate` to compare the last object of a to-many relationship in Core Data?

For example:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(LAST messages.userId = %i)", myUserId];
```

`messages` is a relationship to-many from `User` -> `Message` entities.

This works:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY messages.userId = %i)", myUserId];
```

but I would like to compare only with the last object of the NSOrderedSet `messages`.

Comment: What do mean by "Last"? Is your to-many relationship ordered? Or do you want the least recent message?

Comment: May be your issue is because NSSet is not ordered. Hop this can be a starting point that can help you.

Comment: @dariaa yes, it's ordered. It's a NSOrderedSet. My mistake writing the question.

Comment: I want to avoid another relation "lastMessage" that I could retrieve the last object.

Comment: Is there any property in `Message` entity that determines the order (i.e. creationDate or index)?

Comment: @dariaa yes, `created`. Why?

Comment: Coming up with an alternative approach for you. Quick question: what is the entity you make a fetch request with this predicate? (Probably the entity that has `messages` relationship)

Comment: Yes: `Chat` has `messages`. I want to request (using NSFetchRequest) all the `Chat`s which last `Message` is from me. That's why `(LAST messages.userId = %i)`.

Comment: Jus to help you understand better: a `message` can be from me or from my friend. I want to get the `Chat` that the last message was from me.

Comment: Right now I have another relationship called `lastMessage` that I can use and it's working (`(lastMessage.userId = %i)`) but for me makes no sense to have 2 relationships. I still think that there is a way to make this. What do you think?

Comment: I do not think that it is possible to use the ordering of a relationship in the fetch request. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394513/core-data-predicate-for-first-element-in-orderd-relationship for a similar question.