# Trying to write a predicate to compare against the first object of a to-many relationship

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I use this predicate `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY lists.name LIKE[cd] %@", listName]` to compare the search string (listName) with an ordered `to-many` relationship named `lists`, however, there is a design requirement that I have to compare the search string (listName) against only the first element of the ordered set in the `to-many` relationship, so I need something like the following pseudocode to be done using a `CoreData` predicate:
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lists.firstObject.name LIKE[cd] %@", listName]`;

thank you in advance

p.s I know it's possible to fetch the first object of that ordered `to-many` relationship and then compare the `listName` against that object, but i won't use this approach 'coz it will be an overhead for the app since this predicate is a part of a big loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Data: Predicate for first element in orderd relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394513/core-data-predicate-for-first-element-in-orderd-relationship) - The author of that question came to the conclusion that this is *not* possible.

Answer (score 2):

Typing on my phone so excuse the brevity.

I'm pretty sure you can do:

```
"lists[0].name like[cd] %@", ...
```

Also:

```
"lists[first].name like [cd] %@", ...
```

HOWEVER, I don't know if Core Data can evaluate that predicate. You'll have to try it and find out.

Comment: unfortunately CoreData couldn't evaluate [0] and [first] crashing with this error: 'Unsupported function expression lists[0].name'

Comment: is there a possible way to post a suggestion to Apple to include such (and other) features into the next CoreData engine with next SDK/iOS releases ? actually this is the second time I got blocked by CoreData, first time was with ALL keyword (although there is workaround for ALL keyword problem).

Comment: @JAHelia absolutely! You can request this feature by filing a new bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com. After you do so, please post the bug number here; I'd love to track its progress internally.

Comment: @DaveDeLong 16402088 wish to see such feature in the next SDK release

Answer (score 2):

I have answered this question before. Ordered relationships have many issues - they are more of a convenience than a hard data modelling feature.

You should simply model the order of the objects as well, e.g. with an attribute `order` of type number. Your predicate is then

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
      @"ANY lists.name LIKE[cd] %@ && order = 1", listName];
```